# Return type of overloaded methods in Java

Tags: java, overloading

[image: Question]
[image: Course Note]

I am taking Java SE11 course. There is nothing about the return type about method overloading in the course video of an instructor. But another instructor is emphasizing that overloaded methods must have the same return type and it is the same in the quiz as well. Do overloaded methods must have the same return type in Java?

Comment: "*Do overloaded methods must have the same return type in Java?*" - Why not try it out?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you even want to do something like that in the first place?

Overloaded methods should do basically the same thing, except using different parameters. As one of my professors used to say, when you're describing what a particular method does, you should never have to use the word "and."

Having different return types would make calling the method very confusing, and if you find that you want to do that it probably means that you need to refactor anyway. (In such a situation, you should probably be using generics or inheritance or perhaps something like the Visitor Pattern instead of overloading).

Answer (score 2):

No, overloaded methods do not need to have the same return type. Take, for example, the following code:

```
public static String foo(String s) {
    return s;
}

public static Object foo(Object o) {
    return o;
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/1clgOr)

In fact, on a language level, the return type is not part of the method's signature (See [JLS, §8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) for details).

As [EJosuhaS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4032703/ejoshuas-reinstate-monica) explained in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67289091/4216641), in most cases overloaded methods will have the same return type, though.

Answer (score 1):

Why not look into the standard library? There’s a `LocalDate` class with an overloaded `atStartOfDay` method that gives you the date and time at the start of day (usually at time 00:00).

```
    LocalDate d = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.APRIL, 26);
    LocalDateTime startOfDayFrom0ArgMethod = d.atStartOfDay();
    ZonedDateTime startOfDayFrom1ArgMethod = d.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("America/Buenos_Aires"));
```

The values returned from the two method calls are:

> ```
> 2021-04-26T00:00
> 2021-04-26T00:00-03:00[America/Buenos_Aires]
> ```

The thing that surprises some here is that the overloaded methods return two different types. The method without parameters returns a `LocalDateTime`, which is a date and time without time zone. This makes perfect sense, there is nowhere a time zone could reasonably come from. The method that takes a `ZoneId` argument, returns a `ZonedDateTime`, which is a date and time *with* a time zone. This makes perfect sense too; we just gave a time zone, so obviously it should be part of the result. On the other hand the different return types may still confuse some. One way to think about it is they are two different methods where it just so happens that the same name fits both.

So I agree agree most of the way with EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica, you need to have strong arguments before you write overloaded methods with different return types. As demonstrated, it’s a question of good design, not a restriction imposed by the language.

Answer (score 0):

In case of overloaded methods,

The method name should be same,
it should be having the same return type and different number of parameters

You can see the methods of wait method in object class.

public final void wait()throws InterruptedException

public final void wait(long timeout,int nanos) throws InterruptedException

public final void wait(long timeout) throws InterruptedException

Answer (score 0):

Not at all.

For example, Java standard library `Math` class has the following static methods:

```
static double   abs(double a)
// Returns the absolute value of a double value.
static float    abs(float a)
// Returns the absolute value of a float value.
static int  abs(int a)
// Returns the absolute value of an int value.
static long     abs(long a)
// Returns the absolute value of a long value.
```

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Obviously, they do not have the same return type.